# Gauss-Markov Theorem

Tags: least-squares

I am struggling with a part of the proof in the Gauss-Markov theorem presented in Hayashi's textbook.

Hayashi defines a class of linear estimators $\tilde{\beta}=Cy$ of $\beta$ where $C$ can depend on matrix of indepedent variables $X$. He further defines $A=(X'X)^{-1}X'$, so that $\tilde{\beta}-b=Cy-Ay=Dy$, where $b$ is the OLS estimator.

Then $\tilde{\beta}=(D+A)y=DX\beta+D\epsilon+b$. Applying $\mathbb{E}(.|X)$ on both sides yields $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{\beta}|X)=DX\beta+\mathbb{E}(b|X)$. Since we also want $\tilde{\beta}$ to represent the class of linear and unbiased estimators, we must have $DX\beta=0$, from which it follows that $DX=0$ (so that it holds for all $\beta$).

Then, $\tilde{\beta}-\beta=D\epsilon+(b-\beta)=(D+A)\epsilon$.

Computing $Var(\tilde{\beta}|X)=Var(\tilde{\beta}-\beta|X)$ yields:

$\sigma^2 [DD'+(X'X)^{-1}]\geq \sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}=Var(b|X)$. The latter result follows from the positive semi-definiteness of $DD'$. I do not see, however, why it need be positive semi-definite. I see that $D$ must be positive definite if $D$ has full column rank and that $X'X$ is positive definite since $X$ has full rank by assumption. But I do not see why $A=(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and $C$ must be pd/psd.

Comment: Re "I do not see ... why it [$DD^\prime$] need be positive semidefinite."  A matrix $A$ is positive-semidefinite if and only if $x^\prime A x \ge 0$ for all vectors $x$.  Plugging $DD^\prime$ in for $A$ in this definition should make its positive semidefiniteness *immediately obvious*.

Comment: So $DD'=(DD')'$ therefore $DD'$ is symmetric. Now, writing $D=[D_1 D_2 ... D_k]$ where $D_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $D$, and substituting in $(Dx)'(Dx)$ yields $([D_1 D_2 .... D_k]x)'([D_1 D_2 .... D_k]x)=(\sum D_i x_i)'(\sum D_i x_i)$ where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ entry of $x$. Denoting $d=\sum D_i x_i$ with typical element $d_i\in\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $([D_1 D_2 .... D_k]x)'([D_1 D_2 .... D_k]x)=(\sum D_i x_i)'(\sum D_i x_i)=\sum d_{i}^{2}\geq 0$. Does this make sense? I am abusing a bit the notation with the index but I suppose the point comes across.

Comment: It's even simpler than that: since $(Dx)^\prime(Dx)$ is the squared length of $Dx$, it's non-negative.